# Illegal offset type when uploading a file PHP

Tags: php

All,
I'm using this input field:

```
<input type="file" name="image_to_upload_image" accept="image/*">
```

I'm then trying to process the file upload with the following code:

```
if ( $_FILES["image_to_upload_image"] ) { 
    echo "it will try and upload";
    $file = $_FILES["image_to_upload_image"];
    print_r($file);
    $newupload = bmt_handle_attachment_new_post($file,$post_id); 
    echo "The newupload is: ".$newupload;
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $newupload );
}
```

Which calls the following function:

```
function bmt_handle_attachment_new_post($file_handler,$post_id,$set_thu=false) {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
        // There was an error uploading the image.
    } else {
        // The image was uploaded successfully!
    }

     // If you want to set a featured image from your uploads. 
    return $attachment_id;
}
```

I'm doing the same thing as this example:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload

Why is it saying illegal offset type?

UPDATE: I have another form that has the same input field except it handles multiple file uploads:

```
<input type="file" name="kv_multiple_attachments[]"  multiple="multiple" >
```

If I then pass it to the following form handler:

```
if ( $_FILES ) { 
    $files = $_FILES["kv_multiple_attachments"];
    $gallery_id = $_POST['gallery_for_upload'];  
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {            
            if ($files['name'][$key]) { 
                $file = array( 
                    'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                    'type' => $files['type'][$key], 
                    'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key], 
                    'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                    'size' => $files['size'][$key]
                ); 
                $_FILES = array ("kv_multiple_attachments" => $file); 
                foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {                          
                    $newupload = bmt_handle_attachment($file,$pid,$gallery_id); 
                        //$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $newupload );
                        //echo "<img src=".$thumb_url.">";
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Then use the same processing function:

```
function bmt_handle_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$gallery_id,$set_thu=false) {
// check to make sure its a successful upload
if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
update_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'bmt_gallery_id', $gallery_id );

 // If you want to set a featured image frmo your uploads. 
return $attachment_id;
}
```

The files are uploaded without an issue.

Comment: What's `$post_id`?  Why are you passing `$_FILES["image_to_upload_image"]` as `$file_handler` and then doing `$_FILES[$file_handler]`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was a copy and paste error. The question is updated.

Comment: Looked good at the time ;) *1st comment deleted*

Comment: If you're doing the same as the link showed, are you using the form that comes with it? I'm under the impression you are, but only showing one line of code for it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The `$post_id` is just an integer value that gets returned from this line of code `$post_id = wp_insert_post( $bmt_post );`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am, just didn't want to show the whole thing because I have other form elements that weren't important. Let me update the question with something that does work.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, a comparison of what works and doesn't may help us.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bmt_handle_attachment_new_post('image_to_upload_image', $post_id)`?  Why are you passing `$file`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Updated with what works correctly.

Comment: In your 2nd, example `$file` is the *key* of the array `foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {`.  So, in your first example, you need to do: `bmt_handle_attachment_new_post('image_to_upload_image', $post_id)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'm assiging the `'image_to_upload_image'` to the `$file` variable.

Comment: You're doing `$file = $_FILES["image_to_upload_image"];`.  That makes `$file` an array.  It just needs to be `$file = "image_to_upload_image";`.

Comment: `Another happy ending` - @RocketHazmat should make it an answer, he deserves the many +1 *and then some* - I was at my wits end lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bmt_handle_attachment` function wants the *name* of the input field as its first parameter.  You are passing it `$_FILES["image_to_upload_image"]` when you should just be passing `"image_to_upload_image"`.

```
$file = "image_to_upload_image";
$newupload = bmt_handle_attachment_new_post($file,$post_id);
```